# Mailscanner Installation. Where to put '/^Received:/ HOLD?'

Tags: linux, centos, mailscanner

I am trying to install Mailscanner onto a Centos VPS and there is a section of the tutorial which I am reading that states the following:

> Next, open the file /etc/postfix/header_checks and add this line:
>   /^Received:/ HOLD
>        This tells Postfix to move all messages to the HOLD queue. Now edit the file /etc/MailScanner/MailScanner.conf and change the
>   following 6 settings, which are all near the top of the file:

My question is, where do I put the new line in the file?

Do I just put it at the bottom?

Comment: Are there any uncommented lines in the file? I'm familiar with postfix in Ubuntu and in a new installation the file does not exist. We create it and since the mails must be sent to hold for mailscanner to scan them you should put it on the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General the order of header_checks is not that important. So you can place the line anywhere in /etc/postfix/header_checks.

Afterwards run

```
postfix check
```

just to make sure the config is fine and chgeck the log output

```
tail -n 50 /var/log/mail.{err,warn}
```

Comment: tail: cannot open `/var/log/mail.warn' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry that line was taken from a Debian based system. On CentOS it's commonly /var/log/maillog